# add bootstrap modal after login in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a boostrap modal just after login in my website.
I have my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#after_login_modal').modal();

});
```

I have my div:

```
<div id="after_login_modal" class="modal bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="after_login_modalLabel">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur purus metus, imperdiet id blandit sit amet,
                ornare et nisl. Nullam elit nunc, fermentum id diam eget, auctor ultricies urna. Ut sodales maximus sodales.
                Fusce lacus libero, blandit quis maximus ut, lacinia in velit. Maecenas ligula leo, cursus vel turpis id, fermentum venenatis purus.
                Donec eleifend nisl auctor ex ullamcorper semper. Pellentesque nec varius elit, sed mollis urna.
                Integer suscipit orci id sapien dapibus vulputate. Suspendisse mollis, est non condimentum vulputate, quam quam suscipit nunc,
                eu blandit nibh massa et augue. Curabitur ultrices pretium massa vel egestas.
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have my action in functions.php:

```
function after_login_display_modal() {
    //stuff
}
add_action('wp_login', 'after_login_display_modal');
```

But I need to integrate everything...and I'm a bit stuck...
Ideal would be load div and javascript only just login.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that in your functions php file, is user has logged in, it will redirect to homepage + *?loggedin=true* so where know the user has logged in.

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ) {
  if( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
    $url = home_url()."?loggedin=true";
    return $url;
  }
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
```

On homepage or wherever you redirect the user, check with php/javascript if *?loggedin=true* exists, and show the bootsrap modal.

Comment: Is there another solution more clean?